# Get FORM information from a given Google Sheet

Tags: google-drive-api

Am using Google Drive SDK Python, To get all information about a sheet from its id.
I have set of sheets and a form is associated to each.

Is there a programmatic way to get the id of the form associated with a sheet.

Or if we provide a form id will we be able to get the sheet where data is going to get populated. Either ways will.

I went app scripts documentation. But I doubt it is also not possible from there.

If any one has any information to share please shared.
If there is no way as of now, @google-drive-sdk team, can this be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this through app scripts, there is a function getDestinationId() which returns  id of response destination.

```
var form = FormApp.openById(id);
var dest_id = form.getDestinationId();
Logger.log(dest_id)
```

In order to use it, you must have set response destination first.

ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getDestinationId()

Comment: hmm this is OK but, is there a way to get the form ID if we have sheets id available.